# Google Chrome is taking forever to set up sync

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, sync, reinstall

I did a clean install of Windows 7 yesterday, and am now trying to sync my bookmarks and other preferences back to Chrome which I had prior to reinstalling Windows.

Unfortunately it is taking forever to do the synchronisation and restore my data. I've checked to see if my Internet connection might be slow and causing this but that's not the case.

Any ideas why it is taking such a long time to synchronise? I searched Google on the issue but all I've found is questions by users having similar issues, but no working solutions. Also, I'm unable to open Chrome Webstore or Extension gallery as when I try to open, it says that "The app is currently unreachable." (The message which is usually displayed when any chrome webapp is tried to open when you're not connected to the network.)

Chrome is really messing up my work, any help will be appreciated, thanks...

Comment: I had the same problem, after a while of pointless syncing, I interrupted it and started it again, then it worked.

Comment: Furthermore Chrome is very "touchy" about the exact way you fine tune you PC. When I move the temp folder for windows and programs the app installer rarely works.

Comment: And an off-topic thing, I guess installation of Chrome is also user specific in Windows machine. Also, it doesn't store cache the way other browsers do, hence, Disk Cleanup utility never clears Chrome's cache. Despite all these odds, nothing's as fast as Chrome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your "user profile" might be corrupt.  Trying this couldn't hurt.

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142059

If you've already sync'd in the past, it should be a pretty painless fix.  Just create a new profile, load Chrome again and sync.

Comment: Before that, try uninstalling and then reinstalling Chrome. This way, you won't lose any of those settings if they're not the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was this :

I had a laptop which was synced correctly but my desktop chrome was out of sync.it was confusing because after accepting my log-in account chrome just faded away (with no message and error) and still was not in synced mode.

all these solutions does not work for me:

- creating fresh **[user profile](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142059)** solution by @Lil'Smokey
- re-installing chrome
- I even turned off my 2-step verification

the solution that worked for me:

1. go **[Google Dashborad](https://www.google.com/dashboard/)** and click **Stop sync and delete data from Google**
2. **Disconnect your Google Account ..** from all your chrome Browsers
3. Reconnect chrome Browsers after 15 minute (to ensure chrome sync server refresh)

Answer (score 0):

first close google chrome

%localappdata%\google\chrome\User Data  < windows 7
delete all the files in there

open up google chrome and sign

but there are syncing issues but it will work for the first time
and then you just have to repeat the process if you want to add new stuff to your browser.

not sure how they will fix that issue xD